# How to create different component base on ListModel in QML

Tags: qt, qml

There are 9 parameters that I need to use TextField1 to input value.

So I use

```
ListModel lstPara { 
    ListElement{
        text:"A";value:"123"
    }...(9 Elements)
}
Grid{
        id: grid
        anchors.fill: parent
        columns: 3
        spacing: 5
        Repeater {
            id: rpPara
            model: lstPara
            delegate: TextField1 {
                      }
         }
}
```

But now there is a parameter that i need to use in another QML type to set the value, all others are used in TextField1.

I tried to define ListModel like this

```
ListModel lstPara{
    ListElement {
        text: "A"; 
        type: 1"; 
        value: "123"
    }
    ListElement {
        text: "B"; 
        type: 2"; 
        value: "321"
    }
    ...(9 Elements)
}
Grid{
        id: grid
        anchors.fill: parent
        columns: 3
        spacing: 5
        Repeater {
            id: rpPara
            model: lstPara
            (some code : like this)
            delegate: {
                  return type === 1 ? 
                  TextField1 {

                  }
                  :
                  another QML type {

                  }
            }
         }
}
```

The code above can not run.
And I don`t want to write 8 TextField1 and 1 another QML type.

So, is there a way to use ListModel?

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly use an Item declaration in a conditional expression like that, but you can do it with a Component. Here's an example of how to do it using a Loader as your delegate, and choosing which Component to load based on the model:

```
ListModel {
    id: lstPara
    ListElement {
        text: "A"
        type: 1
        value: "123"
    }
    ListElement {
        text: "B"
        type: 2
        value: "321"
    }
}
Grid {
    id:grid
    anchors.fill: parent
    columns: 3
    spacing: 5
    Repeater {
        id: rpPara
        model: lstPara
        delegate: Loader {
            sourceComponent: type === 1 ? someText : otherText
            onLoaded: {
                item.text = text
                item.value = value
            }
        }
    }
    Component {
        id: someText
        Text {
            property string value
            color: "blue"
        }
    }
    Component {
        id: otherText
        Text {
            property string value
            color: "red"
        }
    }
}
```